# Run program with parameters C

Tags: c, type-conversion

I need help how to make program run with parameters. I need it to run like : ./name_of_program parameter1 parameter2
I need it to set parameteres in data[] table.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_arp.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define INTERFACE   "eth0"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts("Wysłanie ramki przez NIC");

    int s_out; /*deskryptor gniazda*/
    int j;

    void* buffer = (void*)malloc(ETH_FRAME_LEN);

    unsigned char* etherhead = buffer;
    unsigned char* data = buffer + 14;

    struct ethhdr *eh = (struct ethhdr *)etherhead;
    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
    int send_result = 0;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int ifindex = 0;

    printf("Argumanty funkcji main:\n----------------\n");
        while(argc--)
            printf("%s\n", *argv++);

    printf("----------------\n");

    socket_address.sll_halen    = ETH_ALEN;

    unsigned char src_mac[6] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x00};
    unsigned char dest_mac[6] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x20};
    memcpy((void*)buffer, (void*)dest_mac, ETH_ALEN);
    memcpy((void*)(buffer+ETH_ALEN), (void*)src_mac, ETH_ALEN);
    eh->h_proto = htons (0x0800);

    data[0] = 0x45;
        //pole-tos
data[1] = 0x00;
        //calkowita-dlugosc
data[2] = 0x00;
data[3] = 0x54;
        //identyfikacja
data[4] = 0x00;
data[5] = 0x00;
        //flagi
data[6] = 0x40;
        //fragment-offset
data[7] = 0x00;
        //ttl
data[8] = 0x40;
        //protocol
data[9] = 0x01;
        //suma-kontrolna
strcpy(data+10, argv[1]);
strcpy(data+11, argv[2]);
        //adres-zrodlowy
data[12] = 0x0a;
data[13] = 0x00;
data[14] = 0x00;
data[15] = 0x14;
        //adres-docelowy
data[16] = 0x0a;
data[17] = 0x00;
data[18] = 0x00;
data[19] = 0x01;
                //naglowek icmp
        //request 0x08
        //reply 0x00
data[20] = 0x08;
        //kod icmp
data[21] = 0x00;
        //suma-kontrolna
data[22] = 0x00;
data[23] = 0x00;
        //identyfikator-BE i identyfikator-LE
data[24] = 0x00;
data[25] = 0x1f;
        //numer-sekwencji-BE
data[26] = 0x00;
data[27] = 0x01;
        //dane-icmp
data[28] = 0x00;
data[29] = 0x00;
data[30] = 0x00;
data[31] = 0x00;
data[32] = 0x00;
data[33] = 0x00;
data[34] = 0x00;

    #if 1 
        s_out = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, ETH_P_ALL);
        if (s_out == -1) 
        {
        printf ("Nie moge otworzyc gniazda s_out\n");
        }

            strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, INTERFACE, IFNAMSIZ);
            if (ioctl(s_out, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) == -1) 
        {
            perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
            exit(1);
        }

            ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
        printf("Pobrano indeks karty NIC: %i\n", ifindex);


socket_address.sll_ifindex  = ifindex;

        send_result = sendto(s_out, buffer, 49, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
        if (send_result == -1) 
        { 
        printf ("Nie moge wyslac danych! \n"); 
        }
            else 
            {
            printf ("Wyslalem dane do intefejsu: %s \n", INTERFACE);
            }

        #if 1
            printf ("Dane do wyslania: \n");
            for (j=0;j<send_result; j++) 
            {
            printf ("%02x ", *(etherhead+j));
            }
            printf ("\n");
        #endif


#endif
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How to input data from command line to this data[]?
strcpy(data+10, argv[1]); 
gives 53
strcpy(data+11, argv[2]); 
gives 54
why is that?

Comment: Hint: `"parameter1"` is `argv[1]` and `"parameter2"` is `argv[2]`.

Comment: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: void* buffer = (void*)malloc(ETH_FRAME_LEN);

Comment: `strcpy(data, argv[1]); strcat(data, argv[2]);` ?

Comment: @bartb Please edit your post and add additional information to the question itself, rather than posting it as comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question just changed significantly, indicating probable trolling.

Comment: suggest, when compiling, to enable all warnings, then fix those warnings.  Currently there are 12 warnings that need fixing.  in gcc, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives a compiler warning/error:

```
data[1] = argv[1];
```

here `data[1]` is of type `char`. and `argv[1]` is of type `char*`. Because `argv` is a list of charpointers (`char*`).

to copy the whole first argument, you can do something like `strcpy(argv[0], data);`, but this doesn't check if the destination `data` has enough space, so long arguments can cause errors.

To insure data has enough space, you can

```
char* data = (char*) malloc(strlen(argv[2]) +1);
```

then you do the same for `etherhead`:

```
char* etherhead = (char*) malloc(strlen(argv[1]) +1);
```

and make a nice structure for them both:

```
struct Buffer{
  char* head;
  char* data;
};

Buffer b = { etherhead, data };

//use them
printf("data: %s \n", b.data);
```

---

if you want to concatenate them in one string it is also possible:

```
char* headerAndData = (char*) malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(argv[2]) +1);

sprintf(headerAndData, "%s%s", argv[1], argv[2]);
```

---

Since you tagged the question with `typeconversion` i will assume that you want data that is not a string. You can do this in various ways, depending on your data type. For integer you can say `int i =  atoi(argv[1]);`. You can also have a look at [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Answer (score 0):

amongst several other problems with the code:

```
In C, do not cast the returned value from malloc()
always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc 
  to assure the operation was successful
```

The argc parameter of main() indicates the number of parameter (including a pointer to the program name as argv[0])

So, with two parameters

```
if( 3 != argc )
{ // then invalid parameter count
    printf( "Usage: %s <parm1> <parm2>\n", argv[0] );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, correct number of parameters

// argv[1] is a pointer to a string that contains the first parameter
// argv[2] is a pointer to a string that contains the second parameter
```

regarding this question:

How to input data from command line to this data[]? strcpy(data+10, argv[1]); gives 53 strcpy(data+11, argv[2]); gives 54 why is that?

if the posted 53 and 54 are decimal values, then they represent '4' and '5'  However, if they are hexadecimal values, then they represent 'S' and 'T'